# Paypal doesn't notify my IPN listener

Tags: php, paypal, listener

I have this code:

```
<?php

// CONFIG: Enable debug mode. This means we'll log requests into 'ipn.log' in the same directory.
// Especially useful if you encounter network errors or other intermittent problems with IPN (validation).
// Set this to 0 once you go live or don't require logging.
define("DEBUG", 1);
// Set to 0 once you're ready to go live
define("USE_SANDBOX", 1);
define("LOG_FILE", "./ipn.log");
// Read POST data
// reading posted data directly from $_POST causes serialization
// issues with array data in POST. Reading raw POST data from input stream instead.
$raw_post_data = file_get_contents('php://input');
$raw_post_array = explode('&', $raw_post_data);
$myPost = array();
foreach ($raw_post_array as $keyval) {
    $keyval = explode ('=', $keyval);
    if (count($keyval) == 2)
        $myPost[$keyval[0]] = urldecode($keyval[1]);
}
// read the post from PayPal system and add 'cmd'
$req = 'cmd=_notify-validate';
if(function_exists('get_magic_quotes_gpc')) {
    $get_magic_quotes_exists = true;
}
foreach ($myPost as $key => $value) {
    if($get_magic_quotes_exists == true && get_magic_quotes_gpc() == 1) {
        $value = urlencode(stripslashes($value));
    } else {
        $value = urlencode($value);
    }
    $req .= "&$key=$value";
}
// Post IPN data back to PayPal to validate the IPN data is genuine
// Without this step anyone can fake IPN data
if(USE_SANDBOX == true) {
    $paypal_url = "https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr";
} else {
    $paypal_url = "https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr";
}
$ch = curl_init($paypal_url);
if ($ch == FALSE) {
    return FALSE;
}
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION, CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $req);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FORBID_REUSE, 1);
//curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CAINFO,"api_cert_chain.crt");
if(DEBUG == true) {
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT, 1);
}
// CONFIG: Optional proxy configuration
//curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXY, $proxy);
//curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPPROXYTUNNEL, 1);
// Set TCP timeout to 30 seconds
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 30);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Connection: Close'));
// CONFIG: Please download 'cacert.pem' from "http://curl.haxx.se/docs/caextract.html" and set the directory path
// of the certificate as shown below. Ensure the file is readable by the webserver.
// This is mandatory for some environments.
//$cert = __DIR__ . "./cacert.pem";
//curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CAINFO, $cert);
$res = curl_exec($ch);
if (curl_errno($ch) != 0) // cURL error
    {
    if(DEBUG == true) { 
        error_log(date('[Y-m-d H:i e] '). "Can't connect to PayPal to validate IPN message: " . curl_error($ch) . PHP_EOL, 3, LOG_FILE);
    }
    curl_close($ch);
    exit;
} else {
        // Log the entire HTTP response if debug is switched on.
        if(DEBUG == true) {
            error_log(date('[Y-m-d H:i e] '). "HTTP request of validation request:". curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT) ." for IPN payload: $req" . PHP_EOL, 3, LOG_FILE);
            error_log(date('[Y-m-d H:i e] '). "HTTP response of validation request: $res" . PHP_EOL, 3, LOG_FILE);
        }
        curl_close($ch);
}
// Inspect IPN validation result and act accordingly
// Split response headers and payload, a better way for strcmp
$tokens = explode("\r\n\r\n", trim($res));
$res = trim(end($tokens));
if (strcmp ($res, "VERIFIED") == 0) {
    // check whether the payment_status is Completed
    // check that txn_id has not been previously processed
    // check that receiver_email is your PayPal email
    // check that payment_amount/payment_currency are correct
    // process payment and mark item as paid.
    // assign posted variables to local variables
    $item_name = $_POST['item_name'];
    $item_number = $_POST['item_number'];
    $payment_status = $_POST['payment_status'];
    $payment_amount = $_POST['mc_gross'];
    $payment_currency = $_POST['mc_currency'];
    $txn_id = $_POST['txn_id'];
    $receiver_email = $_POST['receiver_email'];
    $payer_email = $_POST['payer_email'];
    $userid = $_POST['custom'];
    if($receiver_email=="yoeltrujil@walla.com"&$payment_amount==7&$payment_status=="completed"&$item_name="ChattiexBot 1.0 BETA"){
           $mail_From    = "IPN@example.com";
      $mail_To      = "flarmiey@gmail.com";
      $mail_Subject = "777VERIFIED IPN1".$userid;
      $mail_Body    = $req;
      mail($mail_To, $mail_Subject, $mail_Body, $mail_From);



    }else{

       $mail_From    = "IPN@example.com";
      $mail_To      = "flarmiey@gmail.com";
      $mail_Subject = "77VERIFIED IPN2".$payment_amount."-".$payment_currency."-".$payment_status."-".$item_name."-".$receiver_email;
      $mail_Body    = $req;
      mail($mail_To, $mail_Subject, $mail_Body, $mail_From);
    }

    if(DEBUG == true) {
        error_log(date('[Y-m-d H:i e] '). "Verified IPN: $req ". PHP_EOL, 3, LOG_FILE);
    }
} else if (strcmp ($res, "INVALID") == 0) {
    // log for manual investigation
    // Add business logic here which deals with invalid IPN messages
    if(DEBUG == true) {
        error_log(date('[Y-m-d H:i e] '). "Invalid IPN: $req" . PHP_EOL, 3, LOG_FILE);
    }

       $mail_From    = "IPN@example.com";
      $mail_To      = "flarmiey@gmail.com";
      $mail_Subject = "777no IPN";
      $mail_Body    = $req;
      mail($mail_To, $mail_Subject, $mail_Body, $mail_From);

}
?>
```

Which basically sends me an email that has a different subject in each if statement. Thing is, when I run the IPN simulator on my IPN listener on my website, it does send me an email, which means that PayPal did send me a request to the ipn listener. When I use the sandbox demo button that redirects to the sandbox PayPal demo paying page and I pay, it does *not* send any email, which means the ipn listener did not even run.

Some help please?

Comment: Do you have IPN enabled in your sandbox account? The simulator will work; but if you don't turn on IPN notifications for your sandbox'ed paypal account you won't get any messages Log on to your Paypal account.
Click Profile under the My Account tab.
Click My selling tools. Click "Update" in the Instant payment notifications section. Click Choose IPN Settings to specify your listener's URL and activate the listener.

Comment: Thank you Chris, but I have found the problem.It is written here below as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

I found the problem.There are two main cases where the IPN code isn't executed as a result of a request from Paypal -

1.Error in code.Invalid code will stop the whole process and therefore
the code in the IPN listener will not work.
2.When creating the Paypal button, you have to put the notify_url variable in
list of variables and write there your IPN listener, also you have to check the variables box.